# RSA encryption chatting for java

Tags: java, encryption, rsa

I want to make secure chatting program for java.
I entered some message, but it makes error such as InvalidKeyException.
please solve it. Thank you!

it is error message!

> === RSA Encryption === java.security.InvalidKeyException: No installed provider supports this key: (null)     at
>   javax.crypto.Cipher.chooseProvider(Cipher.java:893)   at
>   javax.crypto.Cipher.init(Cipher.java:1249)    at
>   javax.crypto.Cipher.init(Cipher.java:1186)    at
>   Crypto.RSACryption.encryptMessage(RSACryption.java:28)    at
>   Chat.Client.sendEncryptMessage(Client.java:236)   at
>   Chat.ClientGUI.actionPerformed(ClientGUI.java:191)    at
>   javax.swing.JTextField.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)    at
>   javax.swing.JTextField.postActionEvent(Unknown Source)    at
>   javax.swing.JTextField$NotifyAction.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
>     at javax.swing.SwingUtilities.notifyAction(Unknown Source)  at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyBinding(Unknown Source)  at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyBindings(Unknown Source)     at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyEvent(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.KeyboardFocusManager.redispatchEvent(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchKeyEvent(Unknown Source)
>     at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.preDispatchKeyEvent(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.typeAheadAssertions(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchEvent(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)

And here is source code on encryptMessage method.

```
    public byte[] encryptMessage(String plainText, PublicKey publicKey) throws NoSuchPaddingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeyException, BadPaddingException, IllegalBlockSizeException {
    System.out.print("\n Plaintext : " + plainText + "\n");
    byte[] t0 = plainText.getBytes();
    for (byte b : t0) System.out.printf("%02X ", b);
    System.out.println("\n Plaintext Length : " + t0.length + " byte");

    System.out.println("\n=== RSA Encryption ===");
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, publicKey);
    byte[] b0 = cipher.doFinal(t0);
    System.out.print("\n\n Ciphertext : ");
    for (byte b : b0) System.out.printf("%02X ", b);
    System.out.println("\n Ciphertext Length : " + b0.length + " byte");

    return b0;
}
```

Comment: You should learn how to debug your code.  The error clearly states that `publicKey`  is null?

Answer (score 0):

Cryptography in Java is a very complex problem. Out of the box, the JVM comes installed with certain "[providers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/crypto/CryptoSpec.html#Provider)". The Provider in java defines an interface for cryptography operations and there are a [list of them available](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/Security.html#getProviders()) for use in the JVM. Each provider implementation has different supported algorithms and keysizes. When you are calling `Cipher.getInstance`, the JVM looks at all of the installed Providers and chooses one to use that supports the algorithm you requested. In your case, the exception is telling you that there was no provider registered with the JVM which supports the type of encryption you are doing. This could be due to a number of reasons.

1. RSA isnt supported with the provider it selected
2. The key size / type isnt supported

When I have wanted to to cryptography in java I use [BouncyCastle](https://www.bouncycastle.org/) as a Provider. You can specify the bouncy castle provider using the other [Cipher.getInstance](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/crypto/Cipher.html#getInstance(java.lang.String,%20java.security.Provider)) method or use BouncyCastle's helper APIs so that you dont have to use the `Cipher` class directly. Check out an RSA [encrypt/decrypt example here](https://github.com/anonrig/bouncycastle-implementations/blob/master/rsa.java).

As a side note, if you plan on using AES 256 or higher and are using the Oracle JDK, you must install [Unlimited Strength JCE components](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce8-download-2133166.html).

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/SunProviders.html

Comment: The cause of this exception is very simple:`cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, publicKey);` is being called with `publicKey` equal to `null`.